# Ruby / CSV - Convert Dos to Unix

Tags: ruby, csv

I currently use: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DosToUnix to manually convert DOS CSVs to UNIX. Just wondering if there's a ruby function for the CSV library that I'm missing? And / or if it's possible build a quick script / Monkey Patch.

Comment: `gsub(/\r/,'')` will remove the carriage returns from any string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The CSV docs say:

> The String appended to the end of each row. This can be set to the special :auto setting, which requests that CSV automatically discover this from the data. Auto-discovery reads ahead in the data looking for the next "\r\n", "\n", or "\r" sequence.

`:auto` is the default, so you should be able to feed your DOS CSV to Ruby unmodified.

However, if you want to convert to UNIX line endings:

```
str.gsub(/\r\n/, "\n")
```